# How to use --range with --continue with cURL?

Tags: curl, download

I want to download a range of bytes of a file but be able to stop or pause the download then resume it again.
I tried:

```
curl url --range 2000-9000 --continue -
```

But it ignores the range.
Are there other tools that could do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
curl -C - --range 2000-9000 url
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please avoid posting 1 line answers with no explanation. Providing additional context regarding why and/or how this command answers the question improves its long-term value [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Regards.